# How to integrate pugjs (jade-lang) with Ember-CLI?

Tags: ember.js, npm, pug, ember-cli, pugjs

I'm new to npm.

I downloaded `ember-cli` to design an application but also I want to install `pugjs` to render the html.

so .. I don't have to write a lot of unnecessary html code .

so is there any way to to integrate `pugjs` (jade-lang) with `Ember-CLI`.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add Broccoli Jade compiler and loaded here for more information check the following resources:

1- https://github.com/sindresorhus/broccoli-jade

2- https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-ember-jade-zurb-express `//Yoeman generator which may help you to scaffold your project.`

However, I strongly recommend you to use [emblemjs](http://emblemjs.com/). An overview of the project is :

```
    p Introducing Emblem.js: a new templating language
      that compiles to Handlebars.js

    ul
      li Indentation-based (like Slim, Jade, HAML, etc.)
      li Compiles to Handlebars

; full compatibility with
     both custom and built-in Handlebars helpers
  li Ember.js-friendly syntax and full compatibility
     with auto-updating functionality.

/ Emblem is HTML5-aware; Render HTML if a line starts with
  known HTML tag, else invoke HB helper or perform property lookup.
  These defaults are easily overridable when necessary.
ul
  each person in people
    li = person.name

section.ember-features
  / easy, natural Ember bindAttr support
  h1 class=foo The class name of this element is bound to `foo`
  p class=isActive:flashing:inactive Ember.js bound css classes

  / implicit Ember action handlers
  a click="doIt" href="#" Hello, how are you doing, #{name}?

/ condense nested content into a single line if that's how you roll
#footer: ul.menu-items: each menu_items: li: a.menu-link href=url: link_text

if something
  p something was true!
else 
  p something was false!
```